# Java Datagram Packet buffer printing extra white spaces and newlines

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I am learning Java networking and am trying to implement a simple UDP server-client program which exchanges messages between server and client. The program is working, but when I print the buffer, a lot of newlines get printed. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code for the server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.net.SocketException;

class Q1Server {
    private DatagramSocket ds;
    private byte[] buff1, buff2;
    private DatagramPacket dp1 = null, dp2 = null;
    private InetAddress clientIP;
    private int clientPort;

    public Q1Server() throws SocketException{
        ds = new DatagramSocket(1234);

        buff1 = new byte[10000];
        buff2 = null;

        while(true) {
            try {
                dp1 = new DatagramPacket(buff1, buff1.length);
                System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
                ds.receive(dp1);
                System.out.print(new String(buff1, "UTF-8"));
                buff1 = new byte[10000];
                clientIP = dp1.getAddress();
                clientPort = dp1.getPort();
                System.out.println("Connected to IP: " + clientIP + " Port: " + clientPort);
                buff2 = ("Thanks for connecting to the server!!!").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                dp2 = new DatagramPacket(buff2, buff2.length, clientIP, clientPort);
                ds.send(dp2);
                String cl = "";
                while (!cl.equals("close")) {
                    dp1 = new DatagramPacket(buff1, buff1.length);
                    ds.receive(dp1);
                    System.out.println("here");
                    cl = new String(buff1, "UTF-8");
                    buff1 = new byte[10000];
                    System.out.println("Client: " + cl);
                }
                buff2 = ("Closing...\nGoodbye!!!").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                dp2 = new DatagramPacket(buff2, buff2.length, clientIP, clientPort);
                ds.send(dp2);
            } catch(IOException i) {
                i.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {
        Q1Server server = new Q1Server();
    }
}
```

And here is the code for client:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Q1Client {
    private DatagramSocket ds;
    private Scanner scanner;
    private InetAddress ip;
    private byte[] buff1, buff2;
    private DatagramPacket dp1 = null, dp2 = null;

    public Q1Client() throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
        ds = new DatagramSocket();
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        buff1 = new byte[10000];
        buff2 = null;
        scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            buff2 = ("Start").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            dp2 = new DatagramPacket(buff2, buff2.length, ip, 1234);
            ds.send(dp2);

            dp1 = new DatagramPacket(buff1, buff1.length);
            ds.receive(dp1);
            System.out.println(new String(buff1, "UTF-8"));
            buff1 = new byte[10000];

            String msg = "";
            while(!msg.equals("close")) {
                System.out.println("here");
                msg = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Typed: " + msg);
                buff2 = msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                dp2 = new DatagramPacket(buff2, buff2.length, ip, 1234);
                ds.send(dp2);
            }          
            dp1 = new DatagramPacket(buff1, buff1.length);
            ds.receive(dp1);

            System.out.println(new String(buff1, "UTF-8"));  

        } catch(IOException i) {
                i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException{
    Q1Client client = new Q1Client();
}
}
```

I think the problem may be due to the size of the buffer. The `byte` buffer array is pre-initialized with the size that large than the actual text being sent. But what is the other way to do it? How do I know the size of the buffer dynamically?

Comment: you are ignoring the length of received packet, e.g.`new String(buff1, "UTF-8")`  -  this will use the complete buffer to create the string. Try the constructor that also has a length parameter: [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,int,int,java.lang.String)) with the length of received packet

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger how do  get the actual length though?

Comment: [getLength](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#getLength()) - "*Returns the length of the data to be sent or the **length of the data received**.*" (like you get the IP and port number)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger that worked. can you put it as an answer so I can close the question?